# Hide icons in sidebar

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I upgraded version 2 > 3 and it now appears to be icons in the sidebar the left of each file/folder (and to the right of corresponding arrow).

I find these icons cluttering, is there anyway to hide them?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way to achieve this is through theming.

If you would like to edit your default theme to remove the folder/file icons, you must install [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer).

Then you can use Sublime's command palette to execute `PackageResourceViewer:Open Resource`.

Click `Theme - Default` followed by `Default.sublime-theme`

Find and edit the section of the theme which handles folder/file icons to match this sample:

```
{
    "class": "icon_file_type",
    "content_margin": [0,0]
},
{
    "class": "icon_folder",
    "content_margin": [0,0]
},
{
    "class": "icon_folder_loading",
    "content_margin": [0,0]
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/jas/d629e902e95e57bd1a84)

Comment: Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked content changes or becomes unavailable. It is better to include the relevant information from the link in the answer itself. Additionally, neither your link nor your answer text describe exactly what to do with the code in the link. Please [edit] your answer to include the code and explain what to do with it and where to put it.

Comment: Thank you. This worked great! Now all that is left to do is make the modified tabs coloured . Unfortunately, the snippet in the wiki does not work (ST3).

Comment: I almost didn't want to upvote because I felt so strongly this should be a standard setting... but that's hardly your fault. :) Worked perfect!

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to change your install, you can also [customize your theme in your personnal folder](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/wiki/Theme-customisation).

For example, under Ubuntu, edit or create this file `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Default.sublime-theme`, and add following settings into it:

```
[
   {
       "class": "icon_file_type",
       "content_margin": [0,0]
   },
   {
       "class": "icon_folder",
       "content_margin": [0,0]
   },
   {
       "class": "icon_folder_loading",
       "content_margin": [0,0]
   }
]
```

(in every settings file, settings are inside an array)

By default, the Packages directories for Sublime Text 3 are located at:

- OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/
- Windows: %APPDATA%/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/
- Linux: ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/

Answer (score 0):

The path is different for sublime 4 on my windows10 x64: **C:\apps\sublime_text_build_4113_x64\Data\Packages\User\Default.sublime-theme**

And I only want to hide icons before the files and keep the icons of the folders. So my **Default.sublime-theme** ends up with the following content.

```
[
   {
       "class": "icon_file_type",
       "content_margin": [0,0]
   }
]
```